# VPC-enabled Lambda function cannot launch/access EC2 in the same VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC enabled Lambda function which attempts to launch an EC2 using a launch template. The EC2 launch step (run_instances) fails with the below generic network error.

*Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Network Error*

I can launch an instance successfully directly from the launch template, so I think everything is fine with the launch template. I have configured the following in the launch template

- Amazon Machine Image ID
- Instance type
- Key Pair
- A network interface (ENI) which I had created before using a specific (VPC, Subnet, Secutity Group) combo.
- IAM role

The Lambda function includes the below code-

```
import json
import boto3
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2_cl = boto3.client('ec2')
    launch_temp = {"LaunchTemplateId": "<<Launch Template ID>>"}
    resp_ec2_launch = ec2_cl.run_instances(MaxCount=1, MinCount=1, LaunchTemplate=launch_temp, SubnetId="<<Subnet ID>>")
```

Few things on the Lambda function-

- I have used the subnet in the run_instances() call because this is not the default vpc/subnet.
- The function is setup with the same (VPC, Subnet, Secutity Group) combo as used in the launch template
- The execution role is setup to be the same IAM role as used in the launch template
- The function as you see needs access only to the EC2, internet access is not needed
- I replaced the run_instances() with describe_instance_status (using the instance id created directly from the launch template) and got the same error.

The error is a network error, so I assume all is fine (atleast as of now) with the privileges granted to the IAM role. I'm sure there would be a different error, if the IAM role missed any policies.

Can someone indicate what I might be missing?

Comment: boto requires the public internet and so if your lambda is in the private vpc, you need a nat gateway.

Comment: @Lamanus- Thanks for your response. I didn't know the boto3 by default requires access to internet. My Lambda code does not access internet, so assumed that internet access is not needed. I'll try providing internet access to my Lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the problem is with your AWS Lambda function being able to **reach the Internet**, since the Amazon EC2 API endpoint is on the Internet.

If a Lambda function is **not** attached to a VPC, it has automatic access to the Internet.

If a Lambda function is **attached to a VPC** and requires Internet access, then the configuration should be:

- Attach the Lambda function only to **private subnet(s)**
- Launch a **NAT Gateway** in a public subnet
- Configure the **Route Table on the private subnets** to send Internet-bound traffic (`0.0.0.0/0`) through the NAT Gateway

Comment: Thanks for your response. The EC2 being launched is within the VPC. Can you please let me know why do you say that the EC2 API endpoint is in the internet? My understanding is that it is within the VPC.

Comment: The endpoint for all AWS API calls is on the Internet (see [AWS Service Endpoints - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)). This means that, for example, an Amazon EC2 instance launch can be requested _from anywhere on the Internet_. This is unrelated to _where_ the instance is launched. If you wish to make calls to AWS wholly _within_ a VPC, then a [VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) is required.

Comment: Thanks. Once I create the EC2 VPC Endpoint, should I include it else where (launch template or run_instances API)? I created a EC2 VPC Endpoint and tested the Lambda function, but it fails with the same network error, hence the question. I probably need to mention the EC2 VPC endpoint somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your VPC does not have an Internet Gateway, but it does have a VPC Endpoint for EC2.

Therefore, to try and reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created a **new VPC** with one subnet but **no Internet Gateway**
- Added a **VPC Endpoint for EC2** to the subnet
- Created a **Lambda function** that would call `DescribeInstances()` and **attached the Lambda function to the subnet**
- Opened the **security group** on the VPC Endpoint and Lambda function to allow all traffic from anywhere (hey, it's just a test!)

My Lambda function:

```py
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='ap-southeast-2')
    print(ec2.describe_instances())
```

**The result:** The Lambda function successfully received a response from EC2, with a list of instances in the region. No code or changes were required.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond. My Lambda needs to access the EC2 in a VPC, so I don't understand why traffic should be allowed from anywhere. Can this not be achieved without opening to outside traffic?

Comment: To make a `run_instances()` call, the Lambda function needs to be able to access the EC2 Endpoint, which is on the Internet (_not_ in the VPC). Therefore, it either needs access to the Internet (via a NAT Gateway) or via a VPC Endpoint for EC2.