# Does an AWS VPC Endpoint Interface require an Internet Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to connect the following services to a VPC with a public and private subnet.
Any traffic should not traverse the public internet.

**Services**

- `sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com`
- `ssm.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com`
- `logs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com`

Reading through [Interface VPC Endpoints (AWS PrivateLink)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html)
, there is no mention of an IGW (Internet Gateway).

However, reading through [Tutorial: Sending a Message ...](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-sending-messages-from-vpc.html), an IGW is provisioned and a route from the subnet where the EC2 instance is.

- When I don't provision an IGW, no services work.
- When I do provision and IGW, SSM works, but not SQS or CloudWatch.

Questions:

1. Is an IGW required?
2. What is the required routing or setup for an service endpoint such as these?

I've checked the below:

- Policy: Full Access
- Subnets: Private, Public
- Routing: Public subnet has 0.0.0.0/0 routed to IGW
- Tested IGW route in private subnet

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: An Internet Gateway is not required to use a VPC Endpoint. See an example here: [VPC-enabled Lambda function cannot launch/access EC2 in the same VPC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57685255/174777) Would you like to pick one service and try to get it working with some help? Please edit your question and let us know how you tested it and how you know that it failed (eg error messages).

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the link, you're right, it does not require an IGW, but only a subset of commands are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the correct answer is that an IGW is **not** required for the service endpoints to work.
However, not all commands work, the below commands can be used for testing.

#### SQS

`aws sqs send-message --region {region} --endpoint-url https://sqs.{region}.amazonaws.com/ --queue-url https://sqs.{region}.amazonaws.com/{queue_id}/{queue_name} --message-body "Test"`

#### SSM

`aws ssm get-parameter --name {test-param-name}`

#### CloudWatch Logs

`aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name {test_log_group_name}`

Comment: That seems strange. Do you have some example of commands that do _not_ work?

Comment: Indeed, it seems that some SQS commands do not work via the VPC Endpoint.  (I tried list-queues, create-queue and get-queue-curl.) Most strange!

Comment: Could it be a permission or configuration issue?